# SnapChat Login - I am trying to implement SCSDK to login with SnapChat in my app, but the app doesn't redirect back

Tags: ios, swift, snapchat

I've followed specific steps from the official docs  and have   implemented SCSDK to login with Snapchat. I added this code to my `SceneDelegate` to redirect back to my app, but it doesn't work --
the `print(url)` works and prints the url, but `SCSDKLoginClient.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: options)` doesn't work at all i even added a debug pointer to check, but nothing .

Is there any solution for this or something i'm missing , and do i have to use SceneDelegate?

Also, I have checked all the data in the `info.plist`, including the scheme, and everything is in place.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    for urlContext in URLContexts {
        let url = urlContext.url
        print(url)
        var options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
        options[.openInPlace] = urlContext.options.openInPlace
        options[.sourceApplication] = urlContext.options.sourceApplication
        options[.annotation] = urlContext.options.annotation
        SCSDKLoginClient.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: options)
    }
}
```

and this is the login function in my `ViewController`:

```
SCSDKLoginClient.login(from: self) { (success, error) in
    if success == true {
        print("OK")
    } else {
        print("NO")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "does nothing" mean? e.g. what specific steps from [the official docs](https://snapkit.com/docs/login-kit-ios) do not work? Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SCSDKLoginClient) are some other relevant questions that might be of help

Comment: the docs are old and most of it not working anymore , also i have seen all the other answers and none of it is working for me :(

Comment: when i click on the continue button after i enter the email & password in the snapchat screen the url in the sceendelegate above gets called but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Turns Out I was using a wrong account to login in snapchat , I forgot I had to use the same developer account or at least add the other account to this one